# Как правильно подключить в python зависимые dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, dllimport

На текущий момент пытаюсь подключиться через Python 3.10 (ctypes, pycharm) к проприетарному API, который использует собственные dll для подключения к API:

1. Работа с API реализовано в виде функций, которые вызываются из dll (__stdcall)
2. dll зависит от кучи других dll (описаны в документации), в том числе нестандартных.

При подключении через python с библиотекой ctypes столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как импортировать все зависимые библиотеки и функции:

1. В примерах в интернете нашел только примеры работы с одним/двумя dll без зависимостей
2. Функция подключения от разработчика возвращает только код ошибки 3 - проблема с подключением (предполагаю, что для подключения используются другие функции)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в python импортировать все зависимые библиотеки и функции?